# I can not understand akka http route dsl structure grammar

Tags: scala, akka-http

Can anyone give me some material? I have read the official docs, but cannot understand its grammar. E.g. I cannot grasp the meaning of the following code:

```
val route =  
  get {
    pathSingleSlash {
      complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>"))
    } ~
      path("ping") {
        complete("PONG!")
      } ~
      path("crash") {
        sys.error("BOOM!")
      }
  }
```

1. What is the type of `route`?
2. Why is it followed by '{}' block?
3. What's the meaning of akka Directive?

Answer (score 1):

1. Route is a type which transforms a request into a future response. In a more formal way it's a function `RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]`.
2. and 3. After you create a route you need to define some "logic" for it. This "logic" is placed in '{}' block. Its name is routing tree.

The routing tree consists of directives. Understand a directive is a small function which can handle a request.

In general I recommend to read once again two chapters of Akka HTTP docs: [Routes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.5/scala/http/routing-dsl/routes.html) & [Directives](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.5/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/index.html).